# Analytic Function: ROW_NUMBER( )

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

I have a table "Invoice"

```
id integer Primary key
customer_id Integer
total Number (*,2)
```

The query is to display all customer_id, total and running serial number to each customer with alias name as 'SNO'. And the records should be displayed in ascending order based on the customer_id and then by SNO.

Hints:

- Analytic Function: ROW_NUMBER( )
- Analytic Clause: query_partition_clause and order_by_clause.

I wrote the below query:

```
Select customer_id,
       total,
       ROW_NUMBER( ) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY customer_id ASC) AS "SNO"
from invoice;
```

But the result is failing.  What is that I am missing. Also what is meant  "the records should be displayed in ascending order based on the customer_id **and then by SNO**".

The result I am getting is as below:
CUSTOMER_ID    TOTAL    SNO
1    70000    1
2    250000    1
2    560000    2
**3    200000    1

3    45000    2**
4    475000    1
**5    50000    1

5    10000    2**
6    600000    1
6    90000    2

Expected result is :
                                                                       CUSTOMER_ID    TOTAL    SNO
1    70000    1
2    250000    1
2    560000    2
**3    45000    1

3    200000    2**
4    475000    1
**5    10000    1

5    50000    2**
6    600000    1
6    90000    2
                                                                            TOTAL Column data is not matching.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: "the result is failing" - what does that mean? Do you get an error? Wrong results? Partitioning and ordering by the same column is odd, and indeterminate; is there some other column like a timestamp you can order by instead? "and then by SNO" doesn't really help as you're generating that...

Comment: Wrong results I am getting. No timestamp column.

Comment: The results you're getting *are* ordered by SNO (though as dnoeth mentioned, you should still have an explicit order-by clause really). You seem to be expecting them to be ordered by total, and for SNO to track that; but your question and the assignment you seem to have quoted doesn't actually say how the 'running serial number' should be found. Changing your `row_number()` to order by `id` or `total` seems the obvious step, but it isn't clear which (if either) would be correct, as that hasn't been specified in what you've shown us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have  not found any order by clause in your query, another issue in which order you want to generate SNO ? by using `id` or  `total` that will impact on your ordering

```
 with cte as
(
select  1  cid, 70000  total from dual
    union all
select 2, 250000 from dual
    union all
select 2, 560000 from dual
union all
select 3, 200000 from dual
    union all
select 3, 45000  from dual
    union all
select 4, 475000 from dual
union all
select 5, 50000 from dual
union all
select 5, 10000 from dual
union all
select 6, 600000 from dual
union all
select 6, 90000 from dual

)Select cid,total,ROW_NUMBER( ) OVER (PARTITION BY cid ORDER BY total ) AS "SNO" from cte order by cid,SNO
```

Comment: @ Zaynul Abadin Tuhin , I got the results through the solution shared by you, somehow my DB was showing wrong answer. Thank you for the query.

Answer (score 3):

You're close, you probably need to order the `row_number` by `id` (assuming it's ascending based on time)

```
Select customer_id,
       total,
       ROW_NUMBER( ) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY id ASC) AS "SNO"
from invoice
order by customer_id, "SNO" -- should be the default anyway (but there's no guarantee)
```